# Why does SVN not update correctly? Is there a workaround besides re-downloading the entire rep

Tags: svn

I'm the only person working on my django svn repo and I get this error every time I try and commit -

```
 svn: Commit failed (details follow):
 svn: Your file or directory 'urls.py' is probably out-of-date
 svn: resource out of date; try updating
```

I've done an update before every commit and I still get this error - does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Paul: Please provide the output of 'svn status'

Answer (score 1):

You may try the [svn cleanup](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re05.html) command. You may rename/move your local urls.py and update the directory. Afterwards, move back and overwrite the recreated urls.py from the repository (make sure you don't miss any changes).

Comment: I like to emphasize: update the directory, not only the file!

Answer (score 1):

You can get this situation when you add a directory without using svn mkdir, or especially if you svn add something but then delete it.

If your urls.py doesn't have local modifications, delete it and then do svn up urls.py.

You can also try svn up --force.