# SVN: Resource out of date; try updating

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm using Win'7 and Tortoise SVN

- Clicked on "SVN Commit" this morning
- A few files were nominated, and I said okay
- SVN went to work.
- All other files where committed properly

One file had problems. This file has been accessed and used exactly the same as all the others. They are source files used as input to make code.

Got an error in red letters...

```
Error: Commit failed (details follow):
Error: File or directory 'SOURCES\MyFileName.s' is out of date; try updating  
Error: resource out of date; try updating`
```

Tried to update, did not copy/paste the error, sorry for the mystery question. I think it was something about a conflict or a tree

File has some strange icon appended to it

```
Error: Commit failed (details follow):
Error: Aborting commit:   
Error: 'C:\...big...long...path...and...MyFileName...'
Error: remains in conflict
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192304/why-does-svn-not-update-correctly-is-there-a-workaround-besides-re-downloading) on Stack Overflow has an answer that says the cause of this error is adding a new subdirectory without using `SVN_MkDir` or something. I have added several subdirectories to my tree with no problem.

What's more, this is just this one file, not any others, and it has been treated the same as others (for months, in fact). I edit, save, and commit it from time to time (exactly the same as the others in the subdirectory).

Another answer suggested `SVN Cleanup` which I tried, with the result of another error message and the file remained "conflicted", whatever that means.

Okay, what's the crime here ?

Just for reference, this is the version of SVN that I'm using

```
 TortoiseSVN 1.6.6, Build 17493 - 32 Bit , 2009/10/19 20:22:18
 Subversion 1.6.6, 
 apr 1.3.8
 apr-utils 1.3.9
 neon 0.28.6
 OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009
 zlib 1.2.3
```

Comment: Seems like you have a conflict. Check this out: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-conflicts.html

Comment: @KevinCrowell, Thanks for the clue. Reading it now.  As best I can tell, I am not in either of the two categories of events that they are describing. I will continue to investigate this. Thanks and plus 1 for knowing and finding this.

Comment: @KevinCrowell, I read a little bit. Does this mean that somebody else has been working on that file ? This is supposedly my own project, space, disk area, the whole works.

Comment: I cannot imagine a case where you could get into a conflict if you were the only person committing to SVN. If you view the SVN log, do you see any other committees?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the *exact* solution but rather a *close enough workaround*:

When I had the exact same issue with subversion running on a Debian VM guest, on a file with *one line changed* and no conflict in sight, what finally worked for me was to copy the file to *another checkout* on my Windows 7 host managed via TortoiseSVN, then commit from there.  I was then able to svn-update the working copy on my Debian guest.